# Why is TFS 2015 Scheduled Build not running?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We recently upgraded from TFS 2012 to TFS 2015, and have set up several build definitions using the vNext interface.  Our build definitions are extremely simple, they consist of a single "Command Line" task, which performs all of our necessary work.

The builds execute properly when using a Gated Check-in, or when queuing manually, but our Scheduled (nightly at 6pm) builds do not execute as expected.

I have attempted granting permissions to the security user/groups that I believe are necessary to properly queue the build to no avail.

So, why is our TFS 2015 scheduled build not running?

Comment: Have you checked the checkbox for building even if nothing has changed? What errors do you get when the build fails? How do you know it hasnt executed as expected?

Comment: There are no errors, the build never queues at all on schedule, and with the vNext builds I don't see a checkbox for building even if nothing changed (that was an option in 2012 with the XAML builds, if I remember correctly), and there are probably a few dozen changes checked into the codeline each day, and I can tell they are not being queued because there is nothing in the queue history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there is a bug in the TFS 2015 vNext build system.  If you choose to create an "Empty" build on the "Create new build definition" window, as I did, the scheduled builds appear to not function properly.

To fix this, you can create a new "Visual Studio" build, then remove all of the tasks, then add your custom "Command Line" task.

Comment: Upon further investigation, I believe that the problem was related to the Build number format field being modified.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your build agent and TFS server are not in the same machine, please try to set your TFS server and the build agent(the machine holding the agent) in the same **time zone**.

And modified one of the build definition to run at xx AM and  waiting for it to see whether the build get triggered.

If it's still not work, double check **Event viewer** both on the TFS server and build agent any related info on the time when the build definition should be started. And you can also create a new scheduled build definition with same settings to try again.

Comment: Build agent and the TFS server are on the same machine.  As far as scheduled build definitions, we actually have several, and none of them have worked since we upgraded to 2015, but they are all new build definitions anyway (we went from XAML to vNext).  I will try creating a brand new one though to see if it works (with many doubts that it will).

Comment: Creating a new build definition yielded the same results, no builds being queued, and there is nothing in the event viewer, as it appears that the TFSJobAgent is not actually looking at the scheduled builds.

Comment: Your hint about creating a new scheduled build definition sent me on the right path, but wasn't the complete answer.  Creating an Empty build first seemed to be the root cause of my issue, and when I created the new build as you mentioned, I created it again with an Empty build definition rather than using a pre-made definition, so the problem still existed.  Creating a build using one of the pre-made options, then removing the tasks seems to have fixed the problem.